# Which single pilot jet has the largest cabin and longest range?

Tags: range

I'm looking to rent a jet for a trip round the world with my friends but also since I have my license and MEIR, I'll be able to fly myself and don't want to hire another pilot.

Which single pilot jet has the largest cabin and longest range?

Comment: How many hours of single pilot business jet experience do you currently have? I doubt you will find anyone to rent you a business jet just because you have a MEIR.

Comment: @MikeSowsun I have 1700 hours of flying a single pilot business jet (Embraer Phenom 300) and 7000 hours of commercial flying (A380 and B777).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_jet) list of light jets, the longest ranges (for single pilot certified jets) are:

1. [SyberJet SJ30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyberJet_SJ30): 2205 NM
2. [Pilatus PC-24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_PC-24): 2035 NM
3. [Embraer Phenom 300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embraer_Phenom_300): 1936 NM
4. [Cessna Citation CJ4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_CitationJet/M2): 1927 NM
5. Cessna Citation CJ3+: 1825 NM

Sorting by max. number of passengers, we get:

1. Pilatus PC-24: 8-11
2. Embraer Phenom 300: 7-10
3. Cessna Citation: 8-9
4. SyberJet SJ30: 5-6

Considering you are already rated for the **Phenom 300**, this is likely your best option. Anything larger will always require a minimum crew of 2.

Comment: I don't like the size of the Phenom 300. Lovely jet to fly, but I'd much rather get a type rating for something else rather than fly it round the world with friends since it's cabin is a bit too small. The Pilatus PC-24 seems to be what I'm looking for so I'll most likely go for that. Thanks!

Comment: Please let us know how you do finding a Pilatus PC-24 to rent because I would like to do the same thing!

Comment: @MichaelHall did you ever manage to get a rental for it?

Comment: @Eros, no… my comment was tongue in cheek because I agree with others that you won’t find one for anything other than a long term lease.

Comment: @MichaelHall Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question! It is in fact hard to rent for a couple days one of those. More so being just a regular person and not a company. Too much risk for the owners of the aircraft being damaged or stolen.

Answer (score 0):

Well the Phenom 300 currently qualifies under this.

But without an ATP ME with a type rating in the Phenom and employment with said charter firm as a pilot, no one is going to rent the thing to you as a pilot and let you fly it.  It’s not like a rental car.